# Improve my validation

Tags: java, performance, validation

When the user enters their ID I want it to be in a specific format, they are mostly explained within the comments. I was wondering if their was an easier more efficient way of doing this. Also whether or not there is a way to change the entered letters to capital the way I've done the code, or any other method.

```
private boolean setCustomerID(String id) {
    //Validates the customerID contains 3 letters a hypthen then 4 numbers
    if ((id.charAt(0) < 'A' || id.charAt(0) > 'Z')
            || (id.charAt(1) < 'A' || id.charAt(1) > 'Z')
            || (id.charAt(2) < 'A' || id.charAt(2) > 'Z')
            || (id.charAt(3) != '-')
            || !isDigit(id.charAt(4))
            || !isDigit(id.charAt(5))
            || !isDigit(id.charAt(6))
            || !isDigit(id.charAt(7))) {
        return false;
        //Checks the user enters P, B or C for first letter
    } else if ((id.charAt(0) == 'P' || id.charAt(0) == 'B' || id.charAt(0) == 'E')
            //Checks the second and third letter are in the correct region
            && ((id.charAt(1) == 'S' && id.charAt(2) == 'C') 
            || (id.charAt(1) == 'S' && id.charAt(2) == 'C')
            || (id.charAt(1) == 'W' && id.charAt(2) == 'A')
            || (id.charAt(1) == 'N' && id.charAt(2) == 'I')    
            || (id.charAt(1) == 'N' && id.charAt(2) == 'E')    
            || (id.charAt(1) == 'N' && id.charAt(2) == 'W')    
            || (id.charAt(1) == 'M' && id.charAt(2) == 'I')    
            || (id.charAt(1) == 'E' && id.charAt(2) == 'A')    
            || (id.charAt(1) == 'S' && id.charAt(2) == 'E')
            || (id.charAt(1) == 'S' && id.charAt(2) == 'W'))){ 
        //    SC (Scotland), WA (Wales), NI (Northern Ireland), NE (North-East), NW (North-West),
        //MI (Midlands), EA (East Anglia), SE (South-East), SW (South-West).
        return true;
    }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Two words: Regular Expression.

Comment: @axiom You have a problem? Use regex. Then you will have two problems. :)

Comment: It's actually quite hard to figure out your validation rules by looking at your code. Can you [edit] your question and describe them in text as well?

Comment: The Code Review site is probably better suited for this question.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is better suited for this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use regex.

```
private boolean matchCustomerID(String id) {
    return id.matches("^[PBE](?:SC|WA|NI|NE|NW|MI|EA|SE|SW)-\\d{4}\\b");
}
```

Comment: Might I suggest `^[PBE](NI|NE|NW|MI|EA|SE|SW)-[0-9]{4}\b`, to ensure that strings like `dPSE-1234` and `PSE-12345` aren't erroneously included?

Comment: Also, `\\d` is a predefined constant that could replace `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are one way of solving the problem. You can compose the pattern in a way that makes maintenance easier. Building on [rcorreia's pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29013369/474189), you can do something like:

```
private boolean setCustomerID(String id) {
  char[] validFirstLetters = { 'P', 'B', 'E' };
  String[] validRegions = { "SC", "WA", "NI", "NE", "NW", "MI", "EA", "SE", "SW" };

  String pattern =
      String.format("^[%s](?:%s)-\\d{4}$", new String(validFirstLetters),
          String.join("|", validRegions));

  return id.matches(pattern);
}
```

Note that this uses `String.join()` from Java 8. If you don't use Java 8 yet, consider  using `StringUtils` from Apache Commons Lang.

Answer (score 0):

Regexp is a great feature, but not easy to write and understand..

In this case, I would follow your way, but I would define some testing method. In this manner the code will be readable and easy to write Unit tests for it.
If you need some change later, you will understand the code.

Example:

```
testForLength();
testForLetters();
testForFirstTwoLetters();
```